# Cutting polygon pour around text

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I was looking around the internet the other day and I saw this PCB picture.

[image]

And since then I am trying to replicate this HIGH VOLTAGE warning using altium

But I cant get the polygon to be cut around the letters as in the picture, insted Altium keeps cutting a rectangle around the whole sentence. Here is a screen shot.

[image]

I know it is a weird thing to ask, but if anyone has an idea on how to replicate this HIGH VOLTAGE warning it will be great.

Comment: Perhaps your clearances are too large and preventing the fill from filling? Check that your constraints match the design rules of your board house. You may also need to make the letters larger (you didn't include scale in your picture).

Comment: I checked in that earlier. I does the same no matter how much big the text is or the clearance value.

Comment: In that case, maybe it has something to do with how the text is managed by Altium. Try creating a DXF in an external tool and then adding it in. IIRC there's no "convert to primitives" option for a string in Altium, but that's probably what needs to happen.

Comment: I think @uint128_t is on the right track (no pun intended)- try the script for converting a bitmap .bmp logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@uint128_t is correct. I do this all the time, especially with company logos.

You need an image of what you want to place as a 1-bit monochrome image. Copy it to the clipboard and paste it into the copper layer in Altium. This step usually fails due to image editing programs providing the clipboard data with too much bit resolution. Paste the image into MS Word and then copy and paste it into Altium (sounds wierd but works).

When pasting the image into Altium, you get to re-size it at that point. I advise making a Union of the components of the image too. When you are happy with the image size and placement in the copper layer, copy the image in Altium and paste it into the relevant Soldermask layer to make it gold (if your finish is gold as in the example picture).

Copper pours around your image can then be easily made to keep the standard clearance distance away from your image.