# What is the best method for placing text on copper?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I've been wondering what is the best method electrically for placing a text on a copper layer?
I have a full GND polygon on the top layer. Should I just make the text a cutout from the solder mask so it will be on GND potential, or should I make a cutout from the polygon and place the text inside on a floating copper layer? I added a picture of the two method, which is better? Or does it even matter?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you specifically want copper text with no soldermask, rather than normal silkscreen text? Are you going to solder over it, ENIG it?

Comment: What's wrong with using the silk screen? Is it because it's an inner layer?

Comment: I want it to differ from silkscreen text, the reason is purely looks, there's no practical reason for it. I saw this on a couple PCBs and I find it aesthetic.

Comment: Which did you see?

Comment: Should I use a blue pen or a black pen?

Comment: Check out https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274385/cutting-polygon-pour-around-text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this question is asked on the aesthetic look of the text then there really is no better way than the look you want to achieve. It comes down to your opinion.

There are some additional things to consider when making that aesthetic choice.

1. You could move the text to be in actual copper but have the cutout around it moved over by the edge of the board / plane. When I do this I try to carefully align the outer edge of the text so that it is right in line with where the edge of the plane copper would have been. Here is an example of how that can look.

[image]

2. You could consider making the text itself be a negative object that cuts holes in the copper layer. Implementing this may very well be CAD package specific. Here is an example of this.

[image]